# Are fanfiction/fanon questions on or off topic?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions, off-topic

Recently, [this question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/what-are-the-evidences-in-behind-the-following-assertions) was asked wanting evidence in regards to 2 assertions. Since the question has been deleted, below is a screenshot for those who can't view deleted questions:

[image: Deleted question]

Looking at the [first link](http://ultradragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Eternal_Super_Saiyan) on *Eternal Super Seiyan*, at the bottom in the categories it says

> **Fan Fiction** | Transformations | Page added by SuperSaiyanKrillin | **Transformation created by SuperSaiyanKrillin** | Power Ups | Super Saiyans | Super Saiyan Form | **Fan Made Transformation** | SSJ Forms | SSJ Forns

It appears that [fan-fiction](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fan-fiction) questions are [on-topic on SciFi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251/are-fan-fics-fair-game-for-this-site), which suggests that they are workable on SciFi, but I am wondering **if fan fiction/fanon questions should be on or off topic here on Anime.SE?**, and if they are on-topic, how should they be quality controlled? (i.e. tags, guidelines, etc)

Comment: if we decide to use a tag for these questions, I suggest "fan-fiction" and synonimizing with "fan" and "fanfiction"

Comment: Is this different than allowing doujinshi, which is also a fan fiction in a sense? Unrelated to that, I remember I answered a fan theory related to DB, which seemed to be accepted by community: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/26363/2516

Comment: @AkiTanaka Wikipedia defines doujinshi as a *"Japanese term for self-published works, usually magazines, manga or novels."* which in a way any story on fanfiction.net is a form of self-publication as an indie posting they game on any side then considers that game as "shipped". but that being said i'm kinda hesitant to group the 2 together as while there are fan made doujinshi of say Madoka which don't follow canon (ie. Mami meeting with that office lady and the 2 fall in love) there is unique dojinshi like Virgin's Empire and Type-Moon first started off as a doujin circle

Comment: @AkiTanaka also in regards to the question you answered that was asking what the canon souce may be for something used in the fandom. it would be like asking *"In a lot of Fanfiction it shows that Nanoha Takamachi can absolutely demolish an enemy yet they instantly fall in love with her afterwards. what is the source to that"* to which we point out that in the Nanoha series people who Nanoha has attack normally changes side, such as Arisa stopped bullying Suzuka when Nanoha slapped her and became best of friend with them and Fate being Nanoha's arch enemy until a Starlight Breaker to the face

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### I would say that questions about fan-fictions are off-topic.

There are a few reasons why I say this:

- People can say whatever they want in a fan-fiction, and sometimes
  they aren't even related to the original anime or manga themselves.
- Often, the answers to fan-fiction questions are, **"We don't know!"**
- Fan-fiction questions can tend to be open-ended due to either bad storytelling or bad links to the original anime or manga, and it is stated in the [help center](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) that:

> Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

- Which leads me to: they distract from questions about **actual** anime and manga. And anime and manga are the whole spirit of this site!

To wrap up, I don't think the users on this site are entitled to answer questions about fictions of varying quality levels. That can get way off-topic, and it would create a whole slew of second-rate questions that people don't want to have getting in the way of legitimate, valuable posts.

Comment: I share some of these reservations, but FWIW we do currently accept questions about doujinshi, which _can_ fall into "fanfiction" (and I don't feel like contesting that policy at all).

Answer (score -4):

I think fanfiction is on topic. Fanfictions provide a story on their own. They have simply a label slabbed on them. If they hadn't these labels, they would be accepted without discussion. <s>We should see them as extension of the normal canon.</s><sup>1</sup> But each fanfiction series is unrelated to other series.

The fear of poor quality questions are without reason, in my opinion, because they won't cause more bad quality question than other stories that are not finished or have lots of loose ends.

If we don't have enough information to answer a question because it was never mentioned in the story or by the author then the only answer is

> We don't know.

But I think it should be made clear, that the question is about non-canon material. This can be done, either by a [fanfiction](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fanfiction) tag or by specific tags for a fanfiction (because I barely read fanfiction, I take a normal scifi fanfic) [the-adventures-of-harriet-potter](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-adventures-of-harriet-potter).

I think we should take both, because the first tag can be used to ask for fanfictions in general, e.g.

> Are there any fanfictions that describe the life of C.C.?

This question could be tagged [code-geass](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-geass) [fanfiction](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fanfiction).

Whether this question is on or off topic is a different discussion that can be had when this one is done.

## TL;DR: Fanfiction is on topic.

<sup>1</sup> I had the misconception that all fanfic is in accordance to canon, which is obviously not the case (how can gender swap be canon?) So a fanfic has its own canon.

Comment: FWIW I don't read fanfiction remotely seriously, but I've seen cases where their content clearly works _against_ the "normal" canon (e.g. because of pervasive misconceptions among fans).

Comment: "If they hadn't these labels, they would be accepted without discussion." This feels questionable to me, in the context of this specific site. If I wrote a story "in itself" about a character identical to _Aku no Hana_'s Nakamura, without the "fanfiction" label, my friends would probably treat it as a serious short-story. Particularly in light of the fact that I have no link to Japan, there would thus be no obvious reason to include questions about such a story here, IMO.

Comment: @Maroon To your first point, on Sci-Fi & Fantasy, fan-fiction is on-topic, but they typically treat it as a separate continuity (e.g. they don't answer questions about Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality from within the Harry Potter book canon).

Comment: A different facet of @Maroon's second point: I've written some original novels that were heavily influenced by anime, but not fan-fiction. I'm not Japanese, so my books aren't real light novels. On the other hand, the creators of Avatar: The Last Airbender are no more Japanese than I am. Should their pseudo-anime be on-topic and mine not?

Comment: By the way, I have some heavy reservations about making fanfics on-topic here, but if we do, I definitely think we should ban questions like "Are there any fanfictions that describe the life of C.C.?"—that's basically a recommendation question. If I came here saying "Are there any anime that take place in British Columbia?" I'm fairly sure it would be closed, and deservedly so.

Comment: @Evilloli to the third point: I already said that that is a different discussion that we must have of we decide to allow fanfic questions.

Comment: @Evilloli to your second point: avatar is on topic, so, as long as it imitates the style of an accepted format it is OK? I don't know what the community consensus is regarding that.

Comment: @Evilloli to your first point: I made an edit to my proposal.

Comment: @Maroon evilloli addresses your second point and I addressed your first point with an edit in my proposal.

Comment: [This thing](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/2535/7579) I did a while ago summarizes our current policy on stuff that's not anime or manga, but I was basically trying to show that Maroon's second point is extremely subtle.

Comment: @Armin in regards to series like Avatar and RWBY we seem to decide these on a case by case basis since The Boondocks (which appears to have some Afro Samurai inspired scenes in it along with the art style) and the original Powerpuff Girls would be off-topic here

Comment: @Memor-X Powerpuff girls is the only one I know and I wouldn't have said that it would be an anime...

Comment: @Armin true however i have read in places people compare powerpuff girls to anime because the characters have "buggy anime eyes" and at times the way Mojo Jojo speaks is compare to that of Asian forced english (the broken kind of english you sometimes see coming from Asian characters in movies who are portrayed in not understanding the US way of life)